# Disproving Submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

Q.2 in the text. By the hint I have shown that it has 2 tangent directions. Now how does it follows that there is no submersion?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because $df_p$ sends two linearly independent vectors (which therefore span $\Bbb R^2$) to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to MSE. If you’re satisfied with the answer, you should accept it so the question doesn't stay on the unanswered list.